# Array being reset to undefined after adding items to it

Tags: javascript, data-structures, recursion, tree

I am trying to construct a hierarchy (tree structure) using JavaScript. For that, I wrote a `Node` class that represents a node in the tree. When I retrieve the data from the database, it's all being retrieved properly (i.e: the root node has the `ParentId` as null, it has 3 children that point to it as the parent, and the descendant nodes are set up properly as well...). But when I try to map them to my JavaScript model, the `Children` property of the root node is ending up being `undefined`. I do not know how that could be posible even though during runtime, when I output the contents of the `Children` property in the console I can see the children nodes being added to it. Here's my code:

```
var Node = function (obj) {
    var self = this;
    var isDefined = obj != undefined;

    self.hasChildren = function () {
        return self.Children.length > 0;
    };

    self.hasParent = function () {
        var p = self.ParentId;
        return !(p == null || p == undefined || p == 0);
    };

    self.addChildren = function (objArray) {
        if (!$.isArray(self.Children)) {
            self.Children = [];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
            self.addChild(objArray[i]);
        }
    };

    self.addChild = function (obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Node) {
            self.Children.push(obj);
        } else {
            var n = new Node(obj);
            self.Children.push(n);
        }
    };

    self.removeChild = function (n) {
        var index = self.Children.indexOf(n);
        if (index > -1) {
            self.Children.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };

    self.Id = isDefined ? obj.Id : null;
    self.ParentId = isDefined ? obj.ParentId : null;
    self.Name = isDefined ? obj.Name : '';
    self.Children = isDefined ? self.addChildren(obj.Children) : [];
    self.TypeId = isDefined ? obj.TypeId : null;
};
```

The way I thought about the `addChildren` method, is that I would pass the raw JSON object coming from the server into the constructor of the `Node` object and then in case it has any children (which essentially have the same properties as the parent), `addChildren` will be called which will in turn create a new `Node` for each element. Eventually, the tree will be built recursively.

So where did I go wrong? Why does the `Children` property end up being `undefined`?

Comment: Show us the code you use for create a Node object and the code that calls a method where `.Children` is undefined.

Comment: @Nucleon, yes that is the intent. The children of a node are just the immediate children of it, not all the descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.Children = isDefined ? self.addChildren(obj.Children) : [];
```

You are setting self.Children equal to the return of `self.addChildren()`. That function has no return.

Here is a couple things I would recommend

```
function Node(obj) {
    // clean constructor moving function definitions to prototype
    var self = this;

    // ensure that we at least have an object passed in
    obj = obj || {};

    // default values at the top
    self.Id = null;
    self.ParentId = null;
    self.Name = '';
    self.Children = [];
    self.TypeId = null;

    // fold in data with $.extend, no need to specify each key manually
    // third object is to overwrite any added Children as those need to be handled seperately
    $.extend(self, obj, { Children : [] });

    // if we have children, add them using the addChildren method
    if (typeof obj.Children !== undefined && $.isArray(obj.Children)) {
        self.addChildren(obj.Children);
    }
}

// using prototype to reduce memory footprint
Node.prototype.hasChildren = function () {
    return this.Children.length > 0;
};

Node.prototype.hasParent = function () {
    var p = this.ParentId;
    return !(p == null || p == undefined || p == 0);
};

Node.prototype.addChildren = function (objArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        this.addChild(objArray[i]);
    }
};

Node.prototype.addChild = function (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Node) {
        this.Children.push(obj);
    } else {
        var n = new Node(obj);
        this.Children.push(n);
    }
};

Node.prototype.removeChild = function (n) {
    var index = this.Children.indexOf(n);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.Children.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Then I can use this like so:

```
test = new Node({ Id : "Something", Children : [{ Id : "Interior", Children : [] }] })
```

Using prototype you reduce the memory footprint and don't create a function reference to each interior function for each `Node` you create. Each `Node` one still will reference it's internal data via a `this` variable.